# react-native to use absolute paths? instead of doing import X from '../../something/X'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm wondering the best way for me to use a full path for my project.

For example, if I am importing a component, I don't want to do `import Component from '../components/Component'`, rather just do `import Component from 'app/components/Component';`

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 10):

To have an absolute path,

I am considering your package.json is in the root.

Inside, your package.json add a new property name with value whatever you want i.e

```
"name": "root"
```

and then import all your routes relative to that route

```
import Component from root/components/Component
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use absolute path by figuring out the name of your app in the package.json name section and then using it in front of your absolute path i.e

```
import Component from MyApp/components/Component
```

Here's more information on describing the issue  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099

Answer (score 3):

I tried many approaches. The one `package.json` file per folder sounds a bit too much for me. Also, I had issues with that, as it would start complaining about my `import React from 'react'` statements.

The best solution I found was [this one](https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/cleaning-up-imports-using-module-resolver-in-react-native-58g8), based on `babel.config.js` (if you're using Expo). It's using [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver), a 40KB lib, millions of downloads. With that you'll have to:

1. Set your `babel.config.js` to something like:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['.'],
          extensions: [
            '.ios.ts',
            '.android.ts',
            '.ts',
            '.ios.tsx',
            '.android.tsx',
            '.tsx',
            '.jsx',
            '.js',
            '.json',
          ],
          alias: {
            app: './src/app',
            helpers: './src/helpers',
            ...
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

This should be enough to work. But, if you're like me, using `typescript`, you may also want to please your IDE by preventing it from complaining about the imports.

2. Edit your `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      "helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I struggled a bit to understand the configuration, because that article is showing `app` as the base folder, whereas I'm using `src`. No big deal, just had to translate it to my scenario. My file structure is as follows, btw:

```
project
 - android
 - ios
 - src
   - app
   - helpers
 index.js
```

Comment: "The one package.json file per folder sounds a bit too much for me." You don't have to put one in every folder, you can just put a single one in your "src" folder and then import everything from there. Much less configuration involved and there are no potential for issues caused by module resolver plugin. In the past I've had module resolver break for no reason which ended up costing me a lot of time and I just had to ditch it entirely for the project. Package.json method will never break

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use this:
import MyUtilFn from 'utils/MyUtilFn';
// Instead of that:
import MyUtilFn from '../../../../utils/MyUtilFn';
```

You can use babel-resolver: [npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).
May it can help you

Answer (score 1):

On top of everyone's answer

You can actually create a `package.json` anywhere in other folders

For instance you have :

```
▾ assets/
  ▸ home/
  ▸ png/
    favicon.png
    icon.png
    splash.png
▾ components/
  ▸ display/
  ▸ filters/
  ▸ forms/
  ▾ images/home/
      feedback.js
    index.js
▸ crud/
```

If you create `package.json` inside assets folder with the value

```
{"name": "assets"}
```

Then you can import in any other JS using `assets/png/someimage.png`

Also you can use babel module resolver, with the `babel.config.js` that is included (if you're using expo)

Modify it to this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          root: ["./"],
          alias: {
            assets: "./assets",
            components: "./components",
            crud: "./crud",
            helpers: "./helpers",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```